# Gradually blend 2 images

Tags: blending, corel-paint-shop-pro

I'm trying to gradually blend 2 images at the center of the canvas, using Corel PaintShop Pro. I wanted to recreate something like [the first part of this video](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/blend-two-images-gradient.html).

[image]

1 and 2 are the images, and the black area is the area where I want to blend both images.

I have tried with masks, layers, opacity, and nothing works as I need to. The closest I got was using a layer and delete portions of the image with the eraser tool and playing with the opacity parameter, but it doesn't look natural, or gradual.

With one mask layer, the best I could achieve was this:

[image: my image]

Any ideas of how I can achieve such effect?

Comment: Have you checked [this tutorial](https://www.paintshoppro.com/en/tips/layers/blend-photos/) from Corel itself? Can you [edit] your question to perhaps upload a sample image that you're having trouble with? Masks should do the trick.

Comment: @Luciano I can't use blend images function because the images are different in size. I wanted to recreate something like the first part of this video helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/blend-two-images-gradient.html I follow the instructions of the video, as close I could replicate them on PSP, but I can't make it look as good as in the video. With one mask layer, the best I could achieve was this pasteboard.co/IUd96pt.png. Maybe this effect can't be made on PSP but on PS???

Answer (score 1):

Following your tutorial link the image on the bottom layer has to be as large as the canvas. The one on the top should be at least half the width or larger.

From there you just need to make the mask go from 0% to 100% opacity, it looks from your attempt that the opacity at the edge of the mask is not 0%. Also the larger the blending band is, the smoother your transition will be.